# Adding linear easing to animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, easing, jquery-easing

The red box increases in height from 0 to its full height, but it does it with swing easing. I can't work out how I can make it linear.

I've tried this, and a few other things, but I can't get it to work:

```
$("#movement").animate({"height": open_height}, {duration: slideDuration }, {easing: linear});
```

Full script:

```
 var sliderHeight = "0";
  var initialDelay = 0;
  var slideDuration = 2500;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#movement').show();
    $('#movement').each(function () {
        var current = $(this);
        current.attr("box_h", current.height());
    });
    $("#movement").css("height", sliderHeight);

    var delay = function() { sliderOpen(); };
      setTimeout(delay, initialDelay);
      });

  function sliderOpen()
  {
    var open_height = $("#movement").attr("box_h") + "px";
    $("#movement").animate({"height": open_height}, {duration: slideDuration });
  }
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vs6yejag/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't add linear in the demo, and it has to be given as string or it will be considered undefined:

```
var open_height = $("#movement").attr("box_h") + "px";
  $("#movement").animate({"height": open_height}, 
   {duration: slideDuration, easing: "linear" });
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/vs6yejag/2/)**

Comment: Spot on, thanks a lot.
Knew I was close to getting it, I had also tried that! But just hadn't used speech marks around it.

Answer (score 1):

See [.animate( properties, options )](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)

> **easing** (default: swing)
>
> Type: `String`
>
> A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.

Try `easing:"linear"` ; where `"linear"` is `String` , in quotes

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vs6yejag/3/